# Set many tags as ENV in locust

Tags: python, locust

Hi I'm looking how to set list of tags using environment variables `LOCUST_TAGS`.
To be more precise I want to get equivalent of `--tags tag1 tag2`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this will help with your original question:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393091/unable-to-use-an-array-as-environment-variable

The question as an example of an array as a env var and the answer covers others ways to do it, depending on what you are actually trying to do.

Alternately, it may just be easier if you checked out Locust’s config file.

https://docs.locust.io/en/stable/configuration.html#configuration-file

You can use a config file to define all the tags you want along with any other options you need and pass it all in all at once.